# Flutter Google Mobile Ads : No virtual method addKeyword

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, google-mobile-ads

Google ads no longer work on my flutter app, I am getting this error :

> No virtual method addKeyword(Ljava/lang/String;)Le3/h$a; in class
> Le3/h$a; or its super classes (declaration of 'e3.h$a' appears in
> base.apk)

Despite last version of the SDK and library :

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'
>
> google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0